# Can we create an object of an interface?

Tags: java, oop, interface, instance, anonymous-class

```java
interface TestA {
    String toString();
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new TestA() {
            public String toString() {
                return "test";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What is the result?

> A. test
> B. null
> C. An exception is thrown at runtime.
> D. Compilation fails because of an error in line 1.
> E. Compilation fails because of an error in line 4.
> F. Compilation fails because of an error in line 5.

What is the answer of this question and why? I have one more query regarding this question. In line 4 we are creating an object of A. Is it possible to create an object of an interface?

Answer (score 93):

What you are seeing here is an [anonymous inner class](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+6+anonymous+inner+class):

Given the following interface:

```java
interface Inter {
    public String getString();
}
```

You can create something like an instance of it like so:

```java
Inter instance = new Inter() {
    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "HI";
    }
};
```

Now, you have an instance of the interface you defined. But, you should note that what you have actually done is defined a class that implements the interface and instantiated the class at the same time.

Comment: I was looking for it. Its a really short and the simple answer. +1 to its simplicity.

Comment: @SheikhAman lol i doubt this OP will ever select a correct answer

Comment: So is it true that actually `System.out.println(innerObject.getString());` was called which is what led to no error whatsoever?

Answer (score 5):

`test` should be the output. This is an example of an anonymous inner class.

This is a very common pattern used with the `Comparator` interface as an emulation of closures.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is not only about the anonymous inner class, this prints test cause it overrides the toString method and while `System.out.println` a Object it implicit call it's toString method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this too... The name of anonymous class is generated!

```java
Inter instance = new Inter() {
    public String getString() {
        return "HI" + this.getClass();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create *an object of an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)*, that implements the interface:

> Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use them if you need to use a local class only once.

If you have an interface, that declares one method `toString`, you can first create a class, that implements this inerface, and then create an object of this class:

```java
interface TestA {
    String toString();
}

class TestB implements TestA {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "test";
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new TestB());
    }
}
```

Or you can create *an object of an anonymous class* to simplify this code:

```java
interface TestA {
    String toString();
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new TestA() {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "test";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

<sup>In both cases it prints `"test"`.</sup>

Answer (score -2):

I don't know the significance of this question. If this is an interview question, then I can say it's okay. But in real time it's not the right approach to implement an inheritance.So coming to the answer of the  question, here what you are doing is an **anonymous inner class** .

Here you are instantiating  a **class** and **implementing the inheritance** by writing,

```
System.out.println(new TestA() {
    public String toString() {
        return “test”;
    }
});
```

and ofcourse the result would be `test`