# Is the instance of the class equal to the instance of the interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface

The program has the next code:

```
public class RxTaskHandler<T> implements OnSuccessListener<T>{

   public RxTaskHandler(MaybeEmitter<T> emitter){
        this.emitter = emitter;
    }

     public static void assignTask(MaybeEmitter<T> emitter){
          RxTaskHandler rxTaskHandler = new RxTaskHandler(emitter);
          task.addOnSuccessListenerr(rxTaskHandler);
    } 

   @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object o) {
        emitter.onNext();
    }

}
```

The question about this line - task.addOnSuccessListenerr(rxTaskHandler). We must add OnSuccessListener interface, but instead of this we add the instance of the class which implements OnSuccessListener. It means we can replace instance of the class (implements necessary interface) by instance of the interface?

Comment: There is no such thing as instance of an interface, since interfaces cannot be instantiated. There are only instances of classes that implement the interface.

Comment: No, you can replace name of supertype (e.g., interface) with name of its' subtype (e.g., `RxTaskHandler`), not other way around.

Comment: You can not instantiate the interfaces. So, you always use the class objects that are implementing the interface.

Comment: Eran, Procrastinator we can create the instance of the interface https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000062/can-we-create-an-object-of-an-interface. This instance will be a simple reference object

Comment: Victor, I thought this only applies to classes (when using extends, not implements).

Comment: @Delphian, it’s a dispute about words. The way I (and most, I believe) use the words, an object is always an instance of exactly one class (and no interfaces). At the same time, it has the *types* of any interfaces that the class implements, as well as of any superclasses of the class.

Comment: Ole, this mean that if a class implements an interface, can I use an instance of this class instead of an interface instance?

Comment: Yes, @Delphian; you not only can, you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

It follows the rule of inheretance.
Here interface acts as parent class and class which implements interface acts as child class.

Comment: I always thought that this only applies to classes, but not to interfaces