# passing Interface as parameter in Method

Tags: java, interface

I have seen  we can pass any types of arguments in Method.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;

public class LastModified {

    public static File lastFileModified(String dir) {
        File fl = new File(dir);
        File[] files = fl.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.isFile();
            }
        });
        long lastMod = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        System.out.println("lastMod:"+lastMod);
        File choice = null;
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.println("File:"+file);
            if (file.lastModified() > lastMod) {
                choice = file;
                lastMod = file.lastModified();
            }
        }
        return choice;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        lastFileModified("D:\\TestFiles");

    }

}
```

Here in listFiles method we are passing Interface thing. It seems that Interface object is being created, but as far I know it cannot be done. It just refer the object of class which implements that interface.

Being said that "It's just a way of saying "this parameter will accept any object that supports this interface. It's equivalent to accepting some object of a base class type, even if you're passing in a subclass." NOT CLEARED

Questions:

```
1) **new FileFilter()** of which class object is being created here ?
2) If we are using interface in class, then why its not implemented in above class ?
3) If its a one more way to implement, then what if that interface would have 10 declared methods ? So Do we need to define all after  **new FileFilter()** ?
```

Can anyone help me to understand this ? I'm really confused here

Comment: [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) - You are initializing an Object that implements the `FileFilter` interface.

Comment: @Zachary, If am creating a class, then why its using Interface name with new ...?

Comment: "The syntax of an anonymous class expression is like the invocation of a constructor, except that there is a class definition contained in a block of code." - [Java Tutorials are great](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions, let's take one by one

**1) `new FileFilter()` of which class object is being created here ?**

It will be an object of anonymous class. See [Can we create an object of an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000062/can-we-create-an-object-of-an-interface)

**2) If we are using interface in class, then why its not implemented in above class ?**

It does not require to implement from main class. You are just referring a interface in your class which does not have to be implemented.

**3) If its a one more way to implement, then what if that interface would have 10 declared methods ? So Do we need to define all after  `new FileFilter()` ?**

Yes in that case, all method needs to be implemented.

Comment: so you mean to say that terminology of implementing interface is same, the only difference here is anonymous class is being created which implements that Interface. And for creating a object of anonymous  class which implements interface and whose reference is Interface type, syntax will be new ImplementedInterface() ...? Is it correct..?

Comment: To create an anonymous class object, you need to do `new ImplementedInterface(){all methods}`.

Comment: Is it creating a class or class automatically gets created first while writing this new FileFilter() ? Because listFiles accepts FileFilter type only ..!

Comment: Yes, it creates a anonymous class of type FileFilter. You may see more info at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: What's a benefit of doing this ? We already have terminology to implement interfaces and use them ..!

Comment: An anonymous inner class can be useful when making an instance of an object of some type and overloading methods, without having to actually create a class. This should be done when that implementation is not required anywhere else.

Comment: So when it creates a object of Anonymous class, 1) Interface type can refer to that object..? 2) What is FileFilter() here..Is it a constructor ..? If not then what..?

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous classes can implement interfaces, and that too without the "implements" keyword.

More stackoverflow links: [Can we create an instance of an interface in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587392/can-we-create-an-instance-of-an-interface-in-java) , [Can we create an object of an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000062/can-we-create-an-object-of-an-interface)

On a side note, You have hit a case of Functional Interface which have been introduced in Java 8. An interface with exactly one abstract method is called Functional Interface.

Read more about functional interfaces here: https://www.journaldev.com/2763/java-8-functional-interfaces